# Tomcat отключить кеширование сервлетов

Tags: java, tomcat

Доброго времени суток. собственно сабж... Гугл перерыл - толку 0...<br>
Я прекрастно понимаю что это не php и необходимо пересобирать проект, подскажите пожалуйста нубу адекватный по трудоемкости и скорости вариант этого действа, а то реально напрягает каждый раз перезагружать сервак и я прекрастно понимаю что это дуристика...<br>
Желательно было бы с примером т.к. я полный нуб в этом деле и мне хватило с головой настройки apache+tomcat, у меня нервы больше не выдерживают ^^<br>
Последней идеей было стирать и возовбновлять содержимое web.xml, лучше чем ребут сервера, но всеравно надеюсь есть нормальные пути...
<p align="right"><small><i>Заранее спасибо...</i></small></p>

Comment: Ничего не понятно, чего вы хотите. Вы хотите во время разработки обновлять проект без редеплоя или вы хотите, чтобы в продакшн кэширование страниц на клиентских машинах не происходило?

Comment: Максимально уменьшить телодвижения редиеплоя...<br>
нет речь не о продакшене, а о комфортном обучении...<br>
Сейчас, мягко говоря, не комфортно... Больше с сервером паришься чтобы посмотреть чем пишешь...

Comment: Сейчас я каждый раз очищаю `web.xml`, потом запрашиваю `/servlet/servletName`, соответственно получаю 404, потом снова возвращаю `web.xml` в обычное состояние, потом обновляю `url`, потом еже несколько секунд ожидания и готово...<br>
Я думаю что я занимаюсь дуристикой поэтмоу и задал сей вопрос...

Comment: Так значит дело не в JSP, а в сервлете?

Comment: Да, я как только поставил Tomcat сразу-же с кешированием JSP разобрался, а вот как быть с сервелатами не имею ни малейшего понятия...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Томкат будет проверять классы в приложении и автоматически редеплоить его, если установить у контекста аттрибут `reloadable="true"`. Если у вас только одно приложение, то можно установить это глобально (применится ко всем) в файле `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml`:

```
<Context reloadable="true">
```

Если приложение большое, то через некоторое время к вам придет `OutOfMemoryError`.

P.S. Серьезные дяди используют JRebel - позволяет автоматически обновлять классы (а также конфиги ко многим фремверкам и проч.) без редеплоя вообще. Сам не использовал, но много читал про это и судя по отзывам - вещь.

Comment: Большое спасибо, действительно помогло :)

Answer (score 1):

Если тебе для разработки надо это - то в Netbeans это "из коробки". Вообще, jsp должны обновляться сами, а сервлеты - только при перезагрузке, если только tomcat не в отладочном режиме. Вообще, в какой-то книжке по яве это было подробно описано.

Comment: С JSP я давно разобрался, с сервелатами кроме как перезапуска сервера и танцов над web.xml пока ничего не придумал...<br>
Я сейчас нахожусь в процессе обучения и реально напрягает по 10 раз в час перезагружать сервер...

Comment: Ну так разрабатывай в Netbeans IDE - очень удобно, ничего перезагружать не надо.

Comment: Да, разрабатывал я и в eclipse и в netbeans, пока учишься мне всех этих наворотов не надо, я пишу коды сейчас по 20-100 строк, зачем мне эту тяжесть тянуть? Если нет другого выбора тогда, наверное, прийдется, неужели единственный адекватный вариант юзать IDE? O_o

Answer (score 1):

В общем, надо различать JSP и сервлеты. Если вы используете exploded war (а вы видимо используете, раз говоите, что правите web.xml), то

для случая JSP ничего делать не требуется. Просто меняете JSP и сервер выдаёт новые.

если речь идёт о сервлетах, то тут сложнее. Дело в том, что классы подгружены в виртуальную машину, так что скомпилировать и подложить класс-файлы недостаточно. Необходим редеплой (если, конечно не запущен режим отладки). Самый просто способ сделать это - "коснуться" файла .reload. Например, с помощью

```
touch .reload
```

Если винды, то можно файл просто удалить.. сервер всё передеплоит и файл появится снова.

Ну и конечно, рано или поздно всё закончится OutOfMemory.

И да, как уже говорил товарищ выше, IDE умеют всё это автоматизировать, так что не приходится делать это всё руками.

Comment: нез наю у меня не канало удаление класса, он то всеравно уже в памяти висел...